# Excel 2016 VBA: IE While Busy method broken (since Windows security update)

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using some code to open Internet Explorer and automatically select loads of options to make it easier for the end user. I've been using the following method to have the macro wait until my page is ready to carry on the method. Since the April Security update for windows ([KB4014985](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4014985/security-only-update-for-the-net-framework-3-5-1-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-and-4)) it's started to break on some macros but not others.

```
 Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("-Page Linked Here-")
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    .Document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl03").Click
    .Document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").Click
    .Document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl03_divDropDown_ctl01").Click
    .Document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl00").Click
    .Document.getElementById("VisibleReportContentctl31_ctl09").Click
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        End With
```

The method

```
 While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Just seems to have randomly stopped working on certain macros, some websites work and some don't, however there hasn't been any updates to the ones that don't work or the ones that do.

I've tried other methods like Sleep, and other ways to write that current method, but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody know the cause or fix for this?

Comment: Could you clarify what the broken or non-working behavior is?

Comment: `While...Wend` is a[n outdated] control flow structure, `Wend` is a keyword. You know what a *method* is? That said you need to define what "broken" stands for.

Comment: When running I get the Run Time Error "Method 'Busy' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed."

By broken I mean it just causes the error and I cannot continue.